# Subprocess.check_call: No module named X

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, python-module

I have a Python 3 code file which I want to run using my Python code (2.7) and thus I wrote the following:

```
# run the  code using a different python environment
python3 = '/usr/bin/python3'
execution_dir = '/path/to/the/dir/'
command = [python3, execution_dir + "mycode.py", "-i" + "/tmp/image.png"]
subprocess.check_call(command, env={'PYTHONPATH': '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'})
```

result is that it does not recognize the modules refered in the Python 3 code, throwing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mrcnn'`.

I think it has something to do with module/package paradigm of Python. I downloaded the Mask_RCNN code from [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) and it works standalone without a problem. However, when I use the above mechanism to invoke an external call with a different `PYTHONPATH`, it behaves like it does not recognize its modules.

Does anyone know why exactly is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.

The problem was that I did not add the project folder to the PYTHONPATH.

```
# run the detection code using a different python environment
python3 = '/usr/bin/python3'
execution_dir = home + '/path/to/executable'
pythonpath = home + '/path/to/project/folder' 
command = [python3, execution_dir + "mycode.py", "-i " + "/path/to/image"]
subprocess.check_call(command, env={'PYTHONPATH': pythonpath })
```